# Imprimir resultado de extracción de array en html

Tags: javascript

```js
let objDos = {
    Dental: [
      {
          HORA: "8:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ANDREA ZUÑIGA",
          PACIENTE: "MARCELA RETAMAL",
          RUT: "11123425-6",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA PIA ZAÑARTU",
          PACIENTE: "ANGEL MUÑOZ",
          RUT: "9878789-2",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "SCARLETT WITTING",
          PACIENTE: "MARIO KAST",
          RUT: "7998789-5",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "FRANCISCO VON TEUBER",
          PACIENTE: "KARIN FERNANDEZ",
          RUT: "18887662-K",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "EDUARDO VIÑUELA",
          PACIENTE: "HUGO SANCHEZ",
          RUT: "17665461-4",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "14:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "RAQUEL VILLASECA",
          PACIENTE: "ANA SEPULVEDA",
          RUT: "14441281-0",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      }
    ]
    }
    
let array = objDos.Dental;
for(item of array){
   let paragraph = []
   for(let value in item){
       paragraph.push(item[value]);
   }
   document.write(`<p class="parrdental">${paragraph.join(" - ")}</p>`);
}
    
    
let consultas = []
let clientes = objDos.Dental;
for(item of clientes){
   consultas.push(item.PACIENTE);
}
console.log(consultas)
        
document.getElementById("consultantes").innerHTML=consultas;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dental</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="consultantes">yyy</div>
    <script src="arreglo-2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

En estos archivos al utilizar

```
 document.getElementById("consultantes").innerHTML=consultas;
```

No renderiza en el navegador la instrucción de innerHTML , ante lo cual no se que puede estar produciendo esta situación, porque utilizo el atributo de id en el bloque de html, lo mismo hago en javascript.
Si bien esto funciona con console.log , no hace lo mismo cuando intento llevar la instrucción a html. La idea es extraer información seleccionada del array , y llevarla al archivo web o pagina web para presentarla .
Intente darle un ancho al div utilizando css , pero no hubo respuesta.

Comment: Este es el mismo código que antes ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes

1)En las siguientes variables:

```
let array = objDos.Dental;
let clientes = objDos.Dental;
```

Almacenas la misma lista `Dental` del objeto `objDos`, podrías reducirlo a solo una variable:

```
let clientes = objDos.Dental;
```

2. Cuando iteras con el primer `for`:

```js
for(item of array){
   let paragraph = []
   for(let value in item){
       paragraph.push(item[value]);
   }
   document.write(`<p class="parrdental">${paragraph.join(" - ")}</p>`);
}
```

Haces un `document.write()` lo cual reescribe el contenido dentro de las etiquetas `<body></body>` (a excepción de la etiqueta `<script></script>`) y la siguiente linea desaparece del *body*:

```
<div id="consultantes">yyy</div>
```

Por tanto si quieres que el ultimo `for` haga efecto en el `id="consultantes"`, puedes eliminar el primer `for` y hacer unos cuantos arreglos para que se vea mas "ordenado":

```
let clientes = objDos.Dental;
for(item of clientes){
   let text = `<p>${item.HORA}, ${item.ESPECIALISTA}, ${item.PACIENTE}</p>`
   document.getElementById("consultantes").innerHTML+=text;
}
```

Nota: simplemente agregué esos tres elementos de item, pero bien puedes agregar los que quieras~

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero sigo con el mismo problema . Rendericé y no aparece texto en el div. Marqué ese div con "yyy" , apareciendo solo eso.

Comment: Me indica la consola del navegador que consultas no está definido. Y si coloco let consultas , aparece que hay un token no esperado

Comment: Ups perdón mi pana, `consulta` lo había eliminado porque lo vi innecesario. Borra la línea consultas.push(text) . Parece que al copiarlo en la respuesta lo deje sin querer jajajaja ya edito

Comment: Si gracias . Ahora renderiza bien.